# Как преобразовать строку

Tags: php

Есть строка типа:

```
text=Mile:year=2010:genre=триллер:country=ку:
```

Из неё нужно получить  ассоциативные массивы (или один многомерный) типа:

```
Array ( [text] => Mile )
```

Вот получилось пока так, но надо как то в цикл запихнуть.

```
$str = 'text=Mile:year=2010:genre=триллер:country=ку:';
$search = explode(':', $str);

$search1 = explode('=',$search[0]);

$out[$search1[0]] = $search1[1];

echo print_r($out);
```

Может с регулярными выражениями будет легче?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```
$array = explode(':','text=Mile:year=2010:genre=триллер:country=ку:');
$arrayLength = count($array);
$result = array();

for($i=0; $i<$arrayLength; $i++) {
   $tempData = explode('=',$array[$i]);
   if(!empty($tempData[0])) { // исключим пустые значения из результирующего массива
      $result[$tempData[0]] = !empty($tempData[1]) ? $tempData[1] : 'Пустое значение';
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я только что и сам догадался, но этот способ более лучший.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'text=Mile:year=2010:genre=триллер:country=ку:';
$search = explode(':', $str);

for($i = 0; $i < count($search); $i++)
{
    $search[$i] = explode('=', $search[$i]);
    if(!empty($search[$i][1]))
    {
        echo $search[$i][0] . ' - ' . $search[$i][1] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: опередили)